# How to match only numbers after a letter?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to match only numbers after `s`

What I've tried

```
$line = "sometext s123 text";
preg_match("/s[0-9]*([0-9])/",$line,$match);

echo $match[0]
```

I'm getting `s123` instead of `123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should capture the numbers in a capture group, and then access *group 1* instead of *group 0*:

```
preg_match("/s([0-9]+)/",$line,$match);
echo $match[1]
```

`$match[0]` will give you complete match including `s`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$line = "sometext s123 123";
preg_match("/s(\d+)/",$line,$match);

echo $match[1];
```